# Civ 5 - Why are Wheat and Bananas listed on the map?

Tags: civilization-5

When out on the map screen if you mouse over hexes, or in the strategic view you can see icons if a hex contains a resource.  Wheat and Bananas show up when you do this, yet they are not luxury/strategic resources.  So why do they show up?

Comment: Because they're delicious?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

They are food resources.  They are similar to luxury/strategic resources in that they give you an additional bonus to the output of the hex if you build their corresponding building on the hex, but unlike luxury/strategic resources they don't provide any bonus other than to the output of the hex, and so they cannot be traded.

Other examples are Fish, Deer, and Sheep.

Comment: Also notice some buildings can affect tiles with those resources - for instance a granary increases the food output from tiles with improved Wheat, Bananas and Deer.

Comment: I am pretty sure I would not want to visit the Deer Granary. I mean, I've heard of a Grist Mill, but a Gristle Mill?!